# I have successfully install virtual host in CentOS server, then what can I do for subdomain?

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, domain

I follow instructions from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7)

And checks that works.

Now what can I do to activate a subdomain. My actual domain is csedu.cf.

I made `/etc/httpd/sites-available/csedu.cf.conf` containing followings.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName test.csedu.cf
    ServerAlias csedu.cf
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/test/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/test/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And link this by `sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/csedu.cf.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/csedu.cf.conf`.

Then go to the browser and type `test.csedu.cf` in the browser that make errors.

[image]

But `csedu.cf` resutls the '/var/www/test/public_html/index.html'

[image]

Comment: Do you have resolve of host `testcsedu.cf`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I don't understand your question.

Comment: When you exec command `nslookup test.csedu.cf` you should get IP of your machine. If you do not get it set record in your DNS server for this host

Answer (score 1):

You've now configured your Apache webserver so that it will know what to do if someone sends it a request for test.csedu.cf.

The next step is adding a DNS record for test.csedu.cf to your DNS information, so that a browser can find out which server the request for test.csedu.cf should be sent to.

The details on how to do that will depend on how the DNS zone csedu.cf is managed. In the standard format for DNS records, the minimum necessary record (in absolute form) would look like this:

```
test.csedu.cf. IN CNAME csedu.cf.
```

The full stop at the end of each DNS name is intentional - in DNS records, it means the name is specified in full and no default domain suffix for that zone file should be added to it. If you specify it in this form to DNS administrator, they will know exactly what you need.

Comment: Where I put this line?

Comment: In your DNS server, wherever you or your DNS provider has it.